# RxAndroidBle multiple characteristics notifications

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, rxandroidble

I know that there are numerous questions about this problem already, but personally, as a newbie to RxBluetooth libraries, none of them gave me a straight answer. I need to connect to a Bluetooth unit and register notifications to all of the 8 characteristics from one specific primary service out of 3. The UUIDs of the specific service and characteristics are known in advance. I'd use the standard Android libraries if it wasn't for the fact, that the device refuses to properly connect to the unit most of the time for no reason.

Comment: Hello. As a newbie on Stackoverflow you may have not yet read the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) – I encourage you to do so. In order to help us answer your question you could show the code you tried, what resources you have already gone through, what findings you have. `the device refuses to properly connect to the unit most of the time for no reason` is not exactly descriptive — please provide more info.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve your issue?